# Python: How do you access a dictionary element within a list without indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a directory of folders and files for each user, and I can't seem to access a dictionary for a folder within a list of all of a user's files **but only using the folder name, not by indexing**.

I could iterate over the list and check if the element is a dictionary with the folder name I'm trying to access, but I felt like there was probably an easier way.

```
userDir = {"User1": [{"folder1": [file1, file2]}, file3], "User2": []}
```

What's the best way I could access the dictionary key "folder1" here?

Comment: You just need to drill down through the dictionary, then enumerate lists: `userDir['User1'][1]` this will give file3, `userDir['User1'][0]['folder1']` gets you to the list of file1 & file2 and this, `userDir['User1'][0]['folder1'][0],` gets you to file one in the dictionary, list, dictionary, list structure:

Comment: Sorry, but I want a way to access the `"folder1"` dictionary if you don't know which position it is inside the list of `"User1"`

Comment: You cannot, you need to access the whole list, then iterate through it, lists are by nature ordered, fixed and enumerated. If you do not know the numeric position then you have not choice but to pull the list and  iterate through the items on the list to view the keys/ items.  It will take a well thought our function....

Comment: Try something, post it here and then ask for feedback once you have an attempt.

Comment: How is this marked as duplicate??

Comment: `for obj in userDir["User1"]:`

Comment: `    if type(obj) == dict:`

Comment: `if "folder1" in obj.keys():

Comment: `print(obj["folder1"])  # Or do something else with "folder1"`

Comment: I'll open a new question